Quarto PDF rendering - Not in outer par mode
When I try to render a quarto book, the html rendering works fine. But there is a trouble with rendering the pdf. I always get the error message ERROR: compilation failed- error LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
There seems to be a problem with embedding figures in the pdf but I cannot find a way to solve the problem. Has anyone experienced the same problem and found a solution for it?
The problem seems to be linked to imgaes in the environment ::: {.column-margin}:::
Here ist the code for the _quarto.yml file:
project:

type: book

book:
  title: "Minimal Example"
  date: "5/4/2024"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    keep-tex: true

And here the code for the index.qmd file:
# Minimal Example

Text

::: {.column-margin}
![Example of an Image](800px-Stack_Overflow_logo.png){#fig-sof}
:::

The image file can be downloaded here: 800px-Stack_Overflow_logo.png
quarto check output
Quarto 1.4.549
[✓] Checking versions of quarto binary dependencies...
      Pandoc version 3.1.11: OK
      Dart Sass version 1.69.5: OK
      Deno version 1.37.2: OK
[✓] Checking versions of quarto dependencies......OK
[✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.4.549
      Path: /Applications/quarto/bin

[✓] Checking tools....................OK
      TinyTeX: v2024.05
      Chromium: (not installed)

[✓] Checking LaTeX....................OK
      Using: TinyTex
      Path: /Users/c40298/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin
      Version: 2024

[✓] Checking basic markdown render....OK

[✓] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
      Version: 3.9.6
      Path: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
      Jupyter: 5.7.1
      Kernels: python3

[✓] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK

[✓] Checking R installation...........OK
      Version: 4.3.0
      Path: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
      LibPaths:
        - /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library
      knitr: 1.44
      rmarkdown: 2.25

[✓] Checking Knitr engine render......OK


Please show a [mre] and also show the intermediate .tex file so we can see where the error comes from.

Sorry, I have now added a minimal example. The problem seems to be the embedding of the picture in a column-margin environment.

Quarto unhelpfully inserts a floating environment in your margin (and several other syntax errors...). You can avoid the compilation error by directly inserting the latex syntax to give quarto less chance to mess it up.
The vertical alignment still isn't correct, because quarto incorrectly inserts empty lines around the margin note, which will insert additional empty paragraphs, but at least this will compile:
---
project:
type: book
book:
  title: "Minimal Example"
  date: "5/4/2024"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    keep-tex: true
---

# Minimal Example

Text

::: {.column-margin}
\includegraphics{Stack_Overflow_logo.png}
\captionof{figure}{\label{fig-sof}Example of an Image}
:::


Thank you so much for answering this question. I posted the same question here quarto-cli. The easiest solution is to put the cross-reference into the .column-margin environment and add cap-location=bottom to ensure that the caption is on bottom.
::: {.column-margin #fig-example-image cap-location=bottom}

![](https://placehold.co/600x400.png)

Example of an Image

:::


Use fig-pos="H" attribute.
# Minimal Example

Text

::: {.column-margin}

![Example of an Image](Stack_Overflow_logo.png){#fig-sof fig-pos="H"}

:::


Details
Since you are using #fig-sof as a figure label (to cross-refer the figure later), Quarto will wrap the figure with the floating environment figure. And to have some control over the position of the floating environment, you need to use fig-pos="H".
